# Is Jones "human-like" in touch?

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

No one really knows what Jones is (the meme for a long time was saying that she is "not a robot!"), but she is almost as old as the Earth itself:

[image]

[image]

We know that she is invulnerable, as she manages to [take a bison head-on](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/comics/00001108.jpg), a [spear to the chest](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=1105) and even a [WWII bomb](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/comics/00001327.jpg).

She had many companions during the aeons, but it is never explained that those relationships were purely platonic or more intimate - hence my question: is it ever explained anywhere is Jones soft, human-like in touch?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the atmospheric reentry sans… uh… reentry vehicle.

Comment: I think we have to assume she is, otherwise it would be almost impossible for her to pass as human.

Comment: She probably is, in spite of her invulnerability (and higher density - she's much heavier then she looks).